# Allocating memory to a pointer of a class

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, qt-mobility

QGeoRoutingManager: http://apidocs.meego.com/1.0/qtmobility/qgeoroutingmanager-members.html

This class doesn't have a constructor.
I have forgotten the way to allocate memory to its pointer.

I did:

```
QGeoRoutingManager *a = new QGeoRoutingManager ();
```

This lands in the error:

```
calculateRoute.cpp:16: error: no matching function for call to ‘QtMobility::QGeoRoutingManager::QGeoRoutingManager()’
../../../../tarBalls/qt-mobility-opensource-src-1.2.0/install/include/QtLocation/qgeoroutingmanager.h:91: note: candidates are: QtMobility::QGeoRoutingManager::QGeoRoutingManager(const QtMobility::QGeoRoutingManager&)
```

What should I pass in there, as per the error message *"const QtMobility::QGeoRoutingManager&"*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a singleton class, you can access it like this:

```
QGeoServiceProvider::routingManager().
```

Check the [docs](http://apidocs.meego.com/1.0/qtmobility/qgeoroutingmanager.html#details)

Answer (score 2):

If the class doesn't have a public (default) constructor, **you** can't (directly) create a new instance of it, neither on the stack nor on the free store (heap). You could only possibly create a copy of an existing one, but the docs don't show a copy ctor available.

Look through the documentation if there is a factory function / class to create instances of that class.

Answer (score 0):

The class `QGeoRoutingManager` does **not** have default constructor. The default constructor is one which doesn't take any argument. If it takes, then they're optional (with default value).

Comment: It has one, yes, but the error clearly shows it's not public.

Comment: @Xeo: I don't see that error clearly says that. Can you help me?

Comment: @Nawaz and @Xeo Did both of you click the link I posted? I couldn't find a default constructor there. This link uses an object of the same class but the way to allocate memory is not shown anywhere.:http://apidocs.meego.com/1.2-preview/qtmobility/qgeoroutingmanager.html#details

Comment: QGeoRoutingManager might be written as an interface (Or a class that is not supposed to directly instantiate). Check if you need a derived class!!

Comment: @Nawaz: Since every class automatically gets a default ctor, if it can't find one, it must be non-public.

Comment: @Xeo: NO, every class doesn't automatically gets default ctor. If you define a ctor that takes parameter, then the compiler doesn't generate default ctor for you.

Comment: @Nawaz: Derp, I'm sleep deprived, excuse that brainfart. :| But the error also only shows the copy ctor as another possibility, so I guess I somehow connected that...

Comment: @Xeo: Anyhow, the error doesn't show that "it has default constructor but it is not public". :D

Comment: @Nawaz: Stop editing your comments to have a completely different meaning. ;P

Comment: @Xeo: OP might call `a.foo()`, does that mean that `foo()` exists in the class?

Comment: @Xeo: See its you who edited your comment. :P.. (Also I just edited my commment to direct my comment at you. I mistakenly wrote @Nawaz, rather than @Xeo :P).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `QGeoRoutingManager * QGeoServiceProvider::routingManager () const`

Check here: https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt-mobility/qgeoserviceprovider.html

Answer (score 0):

The class does have a constructor; all classes have a constructor.  The
class apparently doesn't have a default constructor.  You don't show us
the class, so we have to guess, but from the error message, the class
does have a copy constructor.  Did you provide it?  As soon as there are
any user defined constructors, the compiler will not generate a default
constructor; you have to provide one of those too.

Comment: Did you "try" to click on the link in my first post?